# stop activity that is started with startActivity in android

Tags: android, android-camera, start-activity

I just wrote a very simple app which opens camera after 6 seconds , now I just want to close the camera programmatically and return to my app's previous activity after 6 second. is this possible?

here is code of opening the camera:

```
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivity(cameraIntent);

        }
    },6000);
```

is it possible to add a handler(for example) code after startActivity(cameraIntent) that closes the camera after some time? what about taking picture automatically after 6 seconds and returning from camera?
I'm an android newbie and I'm not so sure about what I can do in an android app.

Comment: You can control the camera inside your own app instead of sending intent, read this 
 https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

Comment: you can't *stop* other app, does not mater who started it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. You are starting an Intent for an app you don't control.